# How to delete cells from one sheet and now get a reference error in other

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am referencing cells and need a solution on how to not get a reference error.

What I am doing is referencing specific cells from one sheet to another. See below:

[image]

This is how I am referencing the cells on the "Email" sheet from the "CL Upcoming" sheet.

[image]

The issue I am experiencing is when a row is deleted from the "CL Upcoming" sheet that it creates a reference error on the row where it once was on the "Email" sheet. In my formula, I added absolute reference to the cells so that it would always be that, but it did not help.

This is what is happening and the desired result. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: You are using an absolute reference to the cell with $C$9. It is doing exactly what you have told it to.

Comment: @Randomhero This same issue is present whether I have absolute or non-absolute referencing.

Comment: Either way, when you are looking at a cell, Excel won't really know you want to reference another one if you delete one. Have you tried looking at a VLOOKUP or something to populate the email table?

Comment: @Randomhero No, I have not used a VLOOKUP for this. I originally didn't see how that would work.

Comment: @Randomhero after trying to do this, I can't figure out how to get it to work. I don't have a lookup because that is what I am trying to do with the references above.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to use the indirect function to reference your cells: =INDIRECT("'CL Upcoming'!C9"). But you will have zeros at the end of the list when rows are deleted

Comment: @ZivkoKozarov I just tried this and it didn't work. I tested with one cell and it populated a ref error.

Comment: Strange, did you put the parameter of INDIRECT between double-quotes? It's a string. Example with spaces to make it clear =INDIRECT(  "  'CL Upcoming'!C9  "  )